# Resolving multiple conflicting versions of System.Web.Mvc when using NuGet as package source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, assembly-reference-path

I have an issue with a project finding multiple versions of the same assembly. `System.Web.Mvc` for example:

[image]

I want to make sure that our MVC projects will never find such an outdated `dll` from anywhere except out NuGet sources.

I realize it's not a good idea to go about removing the conflicting versions from system since a lot of applications may be depending on them. For example, this one was found in `C:\Program Files (x86)`

**Update:**

Since we use NuGet, I changed the:

`Project > Properties > Build > Output > Output path:` to `C:\Temp\Drop`

in every project (we have some portable area class library projects aswell) and then

`Project > Properties > Reference Paths` and added `C:\Temp\Drop`

And the problem went away.

Would this be the correct way of going about it or am I just opening another can on worms here?

Comment: Do you have resharper or some other similar plugin?

Comment: The GAC is used at runtime - it's not used at design/compile time by visual studio. However you're getting the reference to version 4.0.0.0, it's *not* coming from the GAC.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, it was looking into different location. Somewhere C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: I just edited and re-scoped the question since this has nothing to do with GAC in the first place.

Comment: If its not GAC then your fix would work, it is similar to system path for binary probing in windows, however you need to ensure the same / similar path on all the deployed systems

Answer (score 2):

Check the following article related to assembly binding and probing, it's quite good:

[MSDN - Assembly Probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Check this [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx) too.

There's a complete hierarchy which is used to find an assembly, for strongly named assemblies GAC would be the first place, in your case you are using strongly named assembly. As explained in the article you should be able to direct your application to the correct assembly version at the runtime

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely have a look at those :)